# How to download icinga and its plugins in ubuntu

Tags: plugins

I am trying to install [Icinga](https://www.icinga.org/) software on my ubuntu machine. I am following the [quick start](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/quickstart-icinga.html) guide and got stuck at step that says: `2.3.5. Download Icinga and the Plugins`.

```
Change to your local source directory i.e. /usr/src

 #> cd /usr/src

Get the current source from the Icinga Website.

Don't forget to download the Monitoring Plugins.
```

I have downloaded the iCinga core from icinga website and the downloaded file is saved to my downloads directory path. I am new to using Ubuntu and also ICinga so please help me how can I install this software.

Also when I go to [Monitoring plugins download page](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/download.html) then I can see a link to download the nagios plugin but not for Icinga. How can I install the monitoring plugins, please help?

Answer (score 2):

> **Install Icinga 2 and its plugins**
>
> Set up the Icinga APT repo:
>
> ```
> cd
> wget -O - http://packages.icinga.org/icinga.key | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://packages.icinga.org/ubuntu icinga-xenial main'
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Install Icinga 2 and several plugins using the Icinga APT repo:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install icinga2 nagios-plugins -y
> ```
>
> To learn more about Icinga 2 plugins, please visit the [Monitoring
>   Plugins Project website](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/).
>
> Start the Icinga 2 service:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl start icinga2.service
> sudo systemctl enable icinga2.service
> ```
>
> By default, the Icinga 2 program will enable three features: checker,
>   mainlog, and notification. You can confirm that using the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> sudo icinga2 feature list
> ```

I found the full installation guide [here on vultr](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-icinga-2-and-icinga-web-2-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to add the PPA and install it from there:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:formorer/icinga
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install icinga
```

For the plugins, you can search for them and install them as you need, just type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install <icingapluginname>
```

Comment: Thanks darent, I am able to install based on your comments but got stuck on how ti install the plugin so taking help from Dumindu answer. Can you please tell me what the ppa is and what is ppa:fomorer?

Comment: The PPA is a source for packages that aren't available in the official Ubuntu repositories, or are in older versions. This is the most updated PPA I've found containing icinga packages, you can see the website here: https://launchpad.net/~formorer/+archive/icinga

Answer (score 0):

Icinga is in Official Ubuntu repository [(packages.ubuntu.com)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=icinga&searchon=names)

You can install it and its pluggins by this command :

```
sudo apt-get install icinga check-mk-config-icinga icinga-cgi icinga-common icinga-core icinga-dbg icinga-doc icinga-idoutils icinga-web icinga-web-pnp nagvis-demos icli libmonitoring-availability-perl  nagvis nagvis-demos
```

Comment: I am trying to use the command you provided but I am facing error saying: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered creating user:
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` Please let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Follow this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22312152